# Can skin creases caused by obesity or exacerbated by poor posture be corrected?

Tags: dermatology

Deep skin creases in people with obesity are common. When weight loss occurs, skin folds are reduced but the creases remain. The same seems to be true of creases deepened by poor posture.

What can be done to reduce or eliminate skin creases? Does aloe vera help?

Comment: Do you mean, 'wrinkles'?

Comment: no these are fat lines which appear on stomach when there is belly fat.they are also called crease lines.

Comment: will aloe vera or lemon help?

Comment: but i heard that lemon contains AHA's and it can help in get ridding of those lines http://www.livestrong.com/article/107229-rid-fat-lines-stomach/

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about stretch amrks. If that's incorrect, please edit the question to include the name for what you mean. A "crease line" is something that only appears on the hands, a far as I know.

Comment: no it is not stretch marks,it is called crease lines or slouching lines

Comment: @YviDe I thought that initially, too. He means fine creases like this; https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-f5ab75ce9eb8ac84de96389c82d28bd1?convert_to_webp=true  - I presume.

Comment: yes but in stomach

Comment: @YviDe - Creases happen all over the body. Major and minor creases exist on every part of your skin. Look just above your palms at your wrists (dorsal or palmar surfaces.) Look at the antecubital fossae, or the popliteal fossae, and the axillae. These are but a very few of the major creases. The minor ones cover the enitre body. It's a common mistake to believe that because one doesn't know something, it does not exist. Palmar (and plantar) creases are only more obvious because of the smoothness/thickness of the surrounding skin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creases form all over your body. Once they do, there is really very little that can be done for them. If you doubt this, consider how much money is spent on cosmetic surgery every year just for facial creases. They can be filled with collagen or other substrate, they can be stretched, the muscles around a crease can be relaxed, decreasing the depth of the crease (this is how botox works), but the crease is there.

Very fine creases (or wrinkles) can be diminished by contact irritants (e.g. retinoic acid preparations, vegetable acids, and other preparations) which cause mild edema (stretching the skin) and reactive skin changes which in toto reduce the appearance of wrinkles.

Obesity normally causes deepening of normal skin folds and the creation of deep skin folds from superficial ones (for example truncal-abdominal skin-folds.) Once this process occurs, the structure of the skin itself is irreversibly changed. If very prominent (for example after weight loss in the morbidly obese), surgery can be done to remove the excess skin and the fold itself (but a scar will replace it).

Aloe vera will not help. However, moisturizers may diminish their appearance a bit, as will good posture.

<sub>[Topical Retinoic Acid for Photoaging: Clinical Response and Underlying Mechanisms](http://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/211166)</sub>
<sub>[Dermolipectomies Following Weight Loss after Surgery for Morbid Obesity](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1381/096089200321593959)</sub>

Comment: what about lemon?i have heard that these contain AHA which will improve the appearence of stretch marks.how to apply it and how long should i keep it?

Comment: My answer is complete. Nothing is really likely to help. Sorry.

Comment: Brilliant answer! I'm not sure if the prognosis is dependent on "How long it's been that way", though. I think that one of the major factors in diminishing these creases, is skin tone. I.e. they're more significant on some than they are on another. I suppose, another factor to consider would be how "big" he was, too.

Comment: @AjaySabarish you should mark this answer as correct ;-) Homeopathic remedies cannot solve all, unfortunately. I answered your question about Lemon juice earlier on; it won't work. Moisturising and building significant muscle mass is your best bet - without medical intervention

Comment: @ user19679 won't AHA's in lemon have an effect?

Comment: @anongoodnurse sir, so according to you mositurizer will reduce the lines a bit?

Comment: @AjaySabarish It will improve skin quality, as in, skin texture. Additionally: as noted by anongoodnurse and myself, moisturiser may diminish the appearance of the imperfections slightly. It's highly dependant on your skin color, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the depth of the creases, however if they are finer then they should be correctable using Hyaluronic Acid fillers. https://www.fda.gov/medical-devices/aesthetic-cosmetic-devices/fda-approved-dermal-fillers

That said, if you are talking about large body folds of fat, then a filler will likely not be an option as the folds would still continue to put pressure onto the folds.